# making ajax call fire only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call that is being fired multiple times.

I have used `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` and `return false` to prevent it from firing more than once. Is there another sure shot way to prevent ajax call more than once.

```
$(document).on('click', '#button1', function(e){
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.page.com',
    data: data,
    method: 'POST',
    success: function(data){

   },
   error: function(err){

   }
});
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [jquery.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) to store a boolean to indicate whether your function has been run before.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#button1', function(e) {
  $button = $("#button1");
  if ($button.data("pressed") !== true) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://non-existentpage',
      data: {},
      method: 'POST',
      success: function(data) {
        alert('ajax');
        $button.data("pressed", true);
      },
      error: function(err) {
        alert('ajax');
        $button.data("pressed", true);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```css
#button1 {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: inline;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button1">ajax</div>
```

Comment: Why go to this extra effort when jQuery already provides the `one()` method?

Comment: indeed `one()` might be a simpler option, but there's just 1 of the many ways to do what was asked, you deserve an upvote

Comment: What about when the button is clicked rapidly or when the ajax call is taking too much time before `success` or `error` callback are triggered??

Answer (score 6):

You can use jQuery [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

```
  $(document).one('click', '#button1', function(e){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.page.com',
        data: data,
        method: 'POST',
        success: function(data){

        },
        error: function(err){

        }
    });
  });
```

```js
var n = null;
$(document).one('click', '#button1', function(e){
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/anonymous/9a6997f09de9b68c59b2/raw/f7d7b756005ad6d2b88cf0211f78a2990d7d2dc7/content.json',
    data: {},
    method: 'HEAD',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
      console.log(jqxhr.getAllResponseHeaders())
      $("body").append("<br>textStatus: " + textStatus + "<br>count: " + ++n)
   },
   error: function(err){

   }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button1">click</button>
```

Comment: Simple and I don't have to track a boolean value!

Answer (score 1):

You could also add a condition checking if the button has already been clicked by setting a variable to true after it has been clicked:

```
window.document_clicked = false;
$(document).on('click', '#button1', function(e){
    if(!window.document_clicked){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://www.page.com',
            data: data,
            method: 'POST',
            success: function(data){
                window.document_clicked = true;
            },
            error: function(err){

            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: jQuery actually includes a `once()` method (http://api.jquery.com/one/) that achieves the same thing without needing a global variable, as in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `async: false` to your current function

or USE `.click`

```
$('#button1').click(function(e){

});
```

Answer (score -1):

Setting async to false means that the statement you are calling has to complete before the next statement in your function can be called.

```
$(document).on('click', '#button1', function(e){
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.page.com',
    data: data,
    async: false, 
    method: 'POST',
    success: function(data){

   },
   error: function(err){

   }
});
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  return false;
});
```

Comment: async will just make it run sequentially?

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead

```
$('#button1').click(function(e){
   $.ajax({
   url: 'http://www.page.com',
   data: data,
   method: 'POST',
   success: function(data){
   },
   error: function(err){

   }
});
```

Much simpler and it should fix that issue of multiple ajax calls.

You also shouldn't have to return false.

Comment: Care to explain down votes?. This solution should work.

Comment: `click` is just an alias to `on`... your example won't change anything and the AJAX request will still be made on each button click.

Comment: Of course it will be fired on each the button is clicked. His problem is he is clicking once and getting the ajax called multiple times.

Comment: Hm, I don't think that is clear from the original question. Either way, your example is no different than the code in the original question except for your use of `click` which, as I described, is simply an alias to `on` (which is what OP is already using)